# Animate CC incorrectly positions dynamic text field

Tags: animate-cc

I have an FLA that I'm publishing to HTML (Canvas). One of my text fields is set to dynamic and is using the web-font [Roboto Condensed](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Condensed), the problem is that when I publish my file the actual text in that field is positioned incorrectly.

For left aligned text the version in the Animate UI has a few pixels of padding within the field at top and left but the published version seems to ignore this and renders the text with no padding, right up against the left and top edges.

Does anyone know if I can either get the browser to render the padding in the original text field OR get Animate to stop adding padding to the field so I can position it on the timeline.

Basically I just want my Animate timeline positioning to match up with what I see when I publish.

Cheers for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Have you embedded the font? Select any of the text fields - open the properties window and embed the font to the swf/html file.

Could cause the text to appear different.
If not you could use a position reference to the stage.width etc.. as oppose to dragging it around.

Good luck!

Comment: My Embed Font button is greyed out and unavailable. I'm using a Google web-font with all the right includes in the template so I would assume it is not necessary to include anything in the actual build. Is that not the point of hosted font services?